Optimizing Spark configurations to enhance the performance of a Databricks job involving numerous joins and shuffles
Notebook Task: The task involves reading data from multiple tables into various dataframes using JDBC, performing 19 joins with filters and transformations, and then writing the final dataframe into a table. I recognize that this approach has its issues, particularly due to the multiple shuffles (joins) before writing to the table. However, my focus is on selecting an appropriate cluster configuration rather than optimizing the code.
Spark UI Details to Analyze the Problem:

Shuffle Read Data: 75 to 89 GB
Shuffle Write Data: 75 to 89 GB
Input Data: 2 GB

To handle this, I provisioned an i3.8xlarge cluster with 256 GB of memory and 32 cores, using 1 to 6 worker nodes and a driver node identical to the workers.
Issue: The job usually completes within 1.5 to 2 hours, but on some days, it takes significantly longer—between 3 to 5 hours. After analyzing, I found that AWS Spot instances were failing on the days with extended run times, causing heavy disk spill. I switched from Spot instances to On-Demand for 4 workers (previously, only 1 was used).
Disk Spill Problem:
The spill issue persists even on regular days. I dug deeper and realized that the high shuffle data requires more executor memory than storage, indicating a memory-intensive workload. Consequently, I switched to r5d.8xlarge (a memory-optimized worker type).
Confusion:
Even after switching to a memory-optimized cluster, the execution time remained the same, and disk spills continued. I tried the following configurations:

spark.executor.memoryOverhead: 16g
spark.sql.adaptive.enabled: true
spark.memory.offHeap.enabled: true
spark.memory.offHeap.size: 40g
spark.executor.memory: 80g
spark.sql.shuffle.partitions: 3000

With these settings, the job ran in 53 minutes, reducing the time significantly, but disk spills still occurred, suggesting further optimization is possible.
I enabled Adaptive Query Execution (AQE) and set spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold to 200 MB, but there was no noticeable improvement. After calculating further, I used these settings:

spark.databricks.adaptive.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold: 209715200
spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold: 209715200

These changes reduced shuffle read/write to about 59 GB, but the job took 1 hour and 10 minutes—longer than the 53 minutes it previously took, despite the reduced shuffle.
Further Configurations Tried:
I added the following configurations:

spark.serializer: org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer (since DBR 15.3 Contains spark 3.5.0 this is not applicable )
spark.memory.storageFraction: 0.1
spark.memory.fraction: 0.7
spark.shuffle.memoryFraction: 0.6 (to allocate more space for shuffle)

Despite reducing shuffle data to 50 GB, the job still took 1 hour and 1 minute. However, there were a few failed tasks.
The shuffle data has reduced, which is good, but I need help identifying the configuration that's missing, as the job still takes longer than expected.
Could anyone assist in understanding and optimizing these settings further?
Thanks for reading!!
Tried to balance cluster configurations with given code and need help in understanding spark configurations

A VERY difficult topic to comment on, or even ask for info. One thing to try is, check which step is causing the spill and at that point in your execution plan, ensure that the size of each partition is small enough to fit in one node's memory. Assumption being, at some stage in your plan, the executor ends up with a partition to process that's bigger than configured memory.

@Kashyap
Thanks for your response! There are three specific stages that are taking longer to complete and causing spill around 20gb combined, each with only a single task. All three stages are involved in the same action, writing data to the table, and I believe each task is handling different portions of data to be written to the same target table. I understand that having a single task per stage can be an issue, but given the complexity of multiple joins, it's somewhat expected and challenging to resolve. I would appreciate any suggestions on how to address this using spark configurations

I have a very similar issue with my spark configuration settings. Hoping to retrieve some insights from here.

I would also recomment @dataengineer_1999 do a read/write before checkpoint in order to cut down the execution plan - this should help with performance. Additionally, always do a predicate-push down (e.g. early filter) + select only the columns you need for the processing this might help with the performance.

Also forgot to mention @dataengineer_1999 try persist() in your massive dataframes this should also help with the memory consumption. Check also if disabling spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled would make a difference given you custom memory spark confs in place
